# PHP array group by data values

Tags: php, arrays, grouping

This is my $data variable:

> cv = 1,2,3,4,5:::cpt = 4,5 ...

Now I need some function, where I can add the number as param (number will be $data number value).

for example.

```
function getPermission($id) {

... return $something;
}
```

Then if I call the function like: `echo getPermission(4);` it'll print out the data 'keys' where the 4 will be inside, as a value.

So, to be clear:

if I call the function like this:

`echo getPermission(4);` output will be "cv" and "cpt".

but if I call it this way:

`echo getPermission(1);`

it'll only output "cv" because number (1) is located in the cv key.

Hope you guys understand, feel free to ask if something aren't clear enough.

Comment: Do you need help parsing `cv = 1,2,3,4,5:::cpt = 4,5 ...`? If not, what format do you have it in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$str = 'cv = 1,2,3,4,5:::cpt = 4,5';
$tmp = explode(':::', $str);
$data = array();
foreach ($tmp as $arr) {
    $tokens = explode(' = ', $arr);
    $data[$tokens[0]] = explode(',', $tokens[1]);
}

print_r(getPermission(4, $data));
print_r(getPermission(1, $data));

function getPermission($id, $data) {
    $out = array();
    foreach ($data as $key => $arr) {
        if (in_array($id, $arr)) $out[] = $key;
    }
    return $out;
}
```

Comment: This is correct except that I will not get $data as a parameter. He did mention that the input to the function will just be $id :)

Comment: Fine. but $data is `cv = 1,2,3,4,5:::cpt = 4,5` ... , not the array.

Comment: @Lucas I added a portion to parse the string into an array.